# unused arguments in R for sample function

Tags: r

i'm trying to prove empirically the non distorsion of an estimator.
what i've written:

```
distorsione = function(nrepl=1e4){

    pop = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,50)
    var.pop = var(pop)

    dim.camp = 4
    
    sample = function(i){
        camp = sample(pop, dim.camp, replace =T)
        media.camp = mean(camp)
        diff = camp-media.camp
        diff2 = diff^2
        sigma2 = sum(diff2)/dim.camp
        return(sigma2)
    }
    sigmas = mapply(sample, 1:nrepl)
    ev = mean(sigmas)
    print(paste("distorsione: ", abs(ev - var.pop)))
    
}
```

when it sample i gives me the error

> Error in sample(pop, dim.camp) : unused argument (dim.camp, replace=T)

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming your outer function `sample` is causing problems because it is overwriting the base version of that function. Your new function only takes one argument so that's why it's telling you you have unused arguments.

Try naming your function something else or if you **really** want it called sample you could change

```
camp = sample(pop, dim.camp, replace =T)
```

to

```
camp = base::sample(pop, dim.camp, replace =T)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `sample` function inside your `sample` function, I believe you wanted to use the former `sample` function in the `base` package and transform it, I encourage you to change the name of your new function :

```
distorsione = function(nrepl=1e4){
  

      pop = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,50)
      var.pop = var(pop)
      
      dim.camp = 4
      
      sample2 = function(i){
        camp = base::sample(pop, dim.camp, replace =T)
        media.camp = mean(camp)
        diff = camp-media.camp
        diff2 = diff^2
        sigma2 = sum(diff2)/dim.camp
        return(sigma2)
      }
      sigmas = mapply(sample2, 1:nrepl)
      ev = mean(sigmas)
      print(paste("distorsione: ", abs(ev - var.pop)))
    }
```